# Are Facebook's "-cx-PRIVATE-" prefix for its CSS class names, protected against Greasemonkey type userscripts?

Tags: javascript, css, facebook, greasemonkey, userscripts

Facebook have started using the "-cx-PRIVATE-" as a naming prefix for many of their CSS class names on their site.

It seems like it is some sort of protection against Greasemonkey type user scripts.

Is it possible that Facebook could intercept calls to document.getElementsByClassName when a query for a classname beginning with "-cx-PRIVATE-" on a facebook web page is made and prohibit the function from returning any results? or would another possibility be that they could change the classnames when a query is intercepted, then change it back again after the query is finished

The reason i ask this, is in certain circumstances, even though i can see in the source code that there are elements with classname beginning with "-cx-PRIVATE-", but when i try and select them via javascript from a userscript, the document.getElementsByClassName function is not returning any elements.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how they are doing this and any way of working around their block?

Comment: I don't see any pages with class names like that.  Please link to one or at least the saved source of one.  Irregardless, this would not stop Greasemonkey scripts.

Comment: it seems it may be a cross browser issue. it seems if i view the source code in chrome, i see the cx-PRIVATE- classes, but if i view the source code in Firefox, i dont see them. very odd.

an example would be in the underlying code of the chevron that opens the "hide story / report as spam" menu, that appears when you hover over a story in the newsfeed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is very possible to override built-in functions. Here is an example for document.getElementsByClassName:

```
// Cache the original
document.______getElementsByClassName = document.getElementsByClassName;
// Overide the function
document.getElementsByClassName = function(classes){
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nmiddleweek/fj52f7f8/5/

Perhaps you could try searching using other DOM query functions?

I don't however have a work-around.

Nick